# Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development. But I've already downloaded it in my PC

Tags: flutter, visual-studio

I've downloaded Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2022, and I've downloaded the [Desktop Development for C++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3frzP.png), yet when I type the command Flutter doctor, it always displays the output [Visual Studio not installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PntWi.png). What may be the problem with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, go to [Download Visual Studio Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/). Download and install the free version, the Community one.

Comment: Sorry for the Chinese characters, I tried to translate it into English but it didn't allow me to. Well the problem seems to be the latest version of Flutter can't detect Visual Studio. So I downgraded flutter to v2.10.5 and it worked! Thanks a lot